# Simplifying and understanding inequalities in two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

given an equation: $$\frac{x-y}{x+y}\ge0$$
What are the steps to simplify this into an understandable group of inequalities which will yield a solution set as a group of areas? I already know that $x+y$ can't equal 0. I even know the shape of the solution areas, it's basically $$|x|\ge|y|$$ excepting points on the line x=-y. I figured this out through some deductive reasoning and testing some points, but I cannot figure out the operations required to arrive at this result in a legitimate (provable) manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{x-y}{x+y}\ge0\iff\left(x-y\ge0\land x+y>0\right)\lor \left(x-y\le0\land x+y<0\right)$$
so the first case gives $x\ge|y|$ but $x\ne-y$ and the second case gives $-x\ge |y|$ but $x\ne-y$ so we conclude that
$$|x|\ge|y|\quad\text{and}\; x\ne-y$$

Comment: The logic symbols "and" and "or" threw me at first, but I think I see where you're going. You're just saying that you just have to evaluate this for each case (where both are positive, and where both are negative). Then the equations can be combined because of the symmetry. Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes this is the meaning! You're welcome.

Comment: Deserves an UV!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  A fraction is positive if the numerator and denominator are both positive, or both negative.

Comment: I can see now where your hint was pointing, but it wasn't clear what you meant until I saw what the other answer contained, so I selected it as the answer. I thank you for your attempt to help me out though.

Comment: (x-y)(x+y)/(x+y)^2 ≥0

Answer (score 0):

One brute force approach is to split into three cases
C1: $x+y<0$, C2: $x+y=0$, C3: $x+y>0$.

You should draw a picture for each of the three cases.

Case C1: If $x+y<0$, then we can write the equation as $x-y \le 0(x+y) = 0$, so the solutions for this case are 
$$\{ (x,y) | x \le y, x+y < 0  \} = \{ (x,y) | x \le y, x < -y  \}  = \{ (x,y) | x < -|y|  \} \cup \{ (x,y) | x = y, y < 0  \} $$

Case C2: The denominator is zero, hence there are no solutions satisfying $x+y = 0$.

Case C3: If $x+y>0$, then we can write the equation as $x-y \ge 0(x+y) = 0$,
so the solutions for this case are 
$$\{ (x,y) | x \ge y, x+y > 0  \} = \{ (x,y) | x \ge y, x > -y  \} = \{ (x,y) | x > |y|  \} \cup \{ (x,y) | x = y, y > 0  \} $$

Now take the union of these solutions, a little work shows that it is equal
to
$$ \{ (x,y) | |x| > |y|  \} \cup \{ (x,y) | x = y, y \neq 0  \} $$